# Java Applet Web deployment problems

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, japplet, cardlayout

I am having trouble deploying a JApplet using netbeans into a working web server. What happens is that it appears to load up the applet, but then upon loading I am simply left with a blank screen and no buttons. I am thinking that could either be because I am using a cardlayout design or because the libraries required are not being included in the .jar. I am using Atmos wrapper functions and a number of external .jar files.

Any help would be awesome! If you need more info please ask!

```
public void init() {

    // initialise any variable we have created
    cloud = new CloudClass();
    user = new User();
    sourceFiles = null;
    dest = null;

    /*
     * Set the Nimbus look and feel
     */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /*
     * If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the
     * default look and feel. For details see
     * http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArFileJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArFileJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArFileJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(ArFileJApplet.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /*
     * Create and display the applet
     */
    try {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                // initialise any previously uninitialised variables
                initComponents();
                invalidLogin_label.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have tweaked around a bit and now the applet page simply comes up with an error on the webpage which says "Error, click for details"

Clicking on this says com/emc/esu/api/EsuException and clicking on the Details button gives me some debug options which may be of help to all the more knowledgeable types..

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache
0-5: set trace level to

Comment: 1) Ensure that every `catch` has an `e.printStackTrace()` 2) Check the Java Console for output. 3) Post the HTML, the applet `init()` method and a link to the test applet as an edit to the question.

Comment: not sure how to provide a link for the test applet, i can link you to the tutorial I followed to create the Web Application

http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/web/applets.html

Comment: @MatthewPigram : There is one thing missing, it seems to me, you hadn't signed your .jar file, so that it can run as Java Web Start, where exactly they taught you in that tutorial to do the same ? [How to Sign a .jar File](http://frequal.com/java/SignAllAppletJars.html), might can help not, not sure though is this the root cause of the problem though :(

Comment: @nIcEcOw how do you sign a .jar file and what does that do? Also im not using java web start in using a java web application to run my program as in the link above... Should I instead use java web start?

Comment: ive tried using java web start, it doesnt seem to do anything, i try viewing the html page and all thats there is the heading and nothing else

Comment: scratch that, its working beautifully :D, thank the gods, so now to run this program on a web server i simply use the html code given or call the launch.jnlp in the jsp file right?

Comment: Ohh yeah, you have to make one html file too, for the JApplet, but if you really wanted to run your JApplet on the web browser, then I guess you need Java Web Start, have a look at my [one project](https://gagandeepbali.uk.to/svn/myrepository/), watch Project tables, that's based on Java Web Start. You be able to see the contents of the .jnlp file and all in that project of mine :-)

Comment: Visit this link on my server [tables.jnlp](http://gagandeepbali.uk.to/gaganisonline/swing/tables/tables/bin/tableapplet.html), that might will give you a feel of what I am saying, what exactly Java Web Start does :-). The username and password for my repository is guest and guest respectively.

Comment: If you use Java Web Start, by virtue of which you can run your Application on the Browser itself, instead of someone first downloading your Application. It's very much like embedding your Swing Application inside your browser. I had given the link, as to how to sign your .jar files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible problems seem most likely:

- The required jars aren't being found on the classpath, so it is exploding with some kind of error. In which case you'll need to find out how to view the ClassNotFoundException and resolve it from there.
- Your UI isn't refreshing / getting laid out correctly after loading. See: [Applet works, but swing components won't appear!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982324/applet-works-but-swing-components-wont-appear)

Comment: im think that the first dot point you have there is most likely, I used the netbeans GUI to design my swing components so surely all that stuff should work right?